# "Pattern match" and recurse on types in closed type family for type equality proof

Tags: haskell, type-families

Assume a situation like this:

```
data Foo a = Foo

type family AlwaysInt a where
  AlwaysInt (Foo a) = AlwaysInt a
  AlwaysInt _       = Int
```

I'd like to prove that `AlwaysInt a` is always `Int`.

```
import Data.Type.Equality

lemma :: AlwaysInt a :~: Int
lemma = undefined
```

How do I prove this? I'd like to "pattern match" on each type in the type family definition since I can prove the lemma for each case, but how do I do such a pattern match?

The ugly workaround is adding an `a` argument to `lemma` and leaving `undefined` there or putting an `error` message, but that's not great in real life situations.

EDIT: Forgot actual problem

Answer (score 4):

You can't prove that.

```
type family Any where {}
type family ManyFoo where
  ManyFoo = Foo ManyFoo
```

What is `AlwaysInt Any`? `Any` is a *stuck type*, so GHC won't be able to reduce the type family application.

What is `AlwaysInt ManyFoo`? Well, `ManyFoo` is an infinite type,

```
ManyFoo = Foo (Foo (Foo ...))
```

so GHC will go into an infinite loop trying to calculate it or trying to calculate `AlwaysInt ManyFoo`.

Comment: Yes, but neither of these types is ever inhabited. Since I need to write `lemma :: a -> AlwaysInt a :~: Int` already to get rid of ambiguous types, can I prove that?

Comment: @Turion, you don't need an `a` to avoid ambiguous types; you just need a `Proxy a`. `ManyFoo` is not *obviously* uninhabited. If you add a `Typeable` constraint and determine that you definitely don't have an application of `Foo` (using `Type.Reflection`) then you can safely `unsafeCoerce` your way to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`:~:` is [defined as](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/src/Data.Type.Equality.html#%3A~%3A) a GADT which is inhabited when `a` is equal to `b`. When that is the case, the inhabitant is called `Refl`. GHC is smart enough to understand that the two types are equal in this case. This compiles

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Type.Equality

data Foo = Foo

type family AlwaysInt a
  AlwaysInt Foo = Int
  AlwaysInt _   = Int

lemma :: AlwaysInt a :~: Int
lemma = Refl
```

If we change one of the `Int` to some other type, we'll get a type error since `Refl` is not a member of `(something strange) :~: Int`.

Comment: Oh yes, nice! It seems like I forgot to post the actual problem when shrinking my real world example to an MWE... how about the updated question now?